# Reading and storing resource key/value pairs from global.resx files in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, globalization

I am implementing globalization in asp.net mvc and i have resource key/values stored in a Global.resx file. 
Now, i need to read all those resource values from that global.resx file and store them in a ViewBag so that i can access ViewBag value in mvc views. 
I dont want to read the value using Resource.getValue(key,culture) option because that will make me to hard-code all the keys in the code, but instead i want to read all the values without specifying the key and store them all in the ViewBag.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources.AppResource is in my case class that holds resource. See code below:

```
        System.Resources.ResourceSet resourceSet = Resources.AppResource.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry item in resourceSet)
        {
            object key = item.Key;
            object value = item.Value;
        }
```